# Typescript : --out directive in VisualStudio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, compilation, typescript

I've seen that it is possible to compile all typescript files into one target `js` file with the `--out` directive. 
Nevertheless, I didn't find the way to do it in VisualStudio 2012.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to edit the project file. Nearish the bottom you'll find a bunch of XML Elements named `TypeScript....` that change the various compilation options - it should be pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Thanks; i will take a glance right now. For the readers, you have to unload the project, and then you can edit the project file.